# How to convert Days in Year(s), Month(s), and Day(s) with Jodatime?

Tags: java, jodatime

How to convert Days in Year(s), Month(s), and Day(s) with Jodatime?

For example:

days = **365**;
should print = **1 Year(s), 0 Month(s), and 0 Day(s)**

```
Days days = Days.days(365);
    Period p1 = new Period(days);

    PeriodFormatter dhm = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days", " Dias").appendSeparator(", ")
        .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months", " Meses").appendSeparator(", e ")
        .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years", " Anos").toFormatter();

    System.out.println(dhm.print(p1.normalizedStandard()));
```

Output console:

```
1 day(s)
```

I also tried print with

```
period.getYears() + " Ano(s), "
+ period.getMonths() + " Mes(es), "
+ period.getDays() + " Dia(s)"
```

Comment: What about a leap year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's basically no such concept. After all, 365 days *isn't* 1 year if you start in a leap year.

What you *could* do is take some "base" date, add your days-based period to that, and then take a year/month/day based period from the result:

```
Period convertToYearMonthDay(Period period, LocalDate referenceDate) {
    LocalDate endDate = referenceDate.plus(period);
    return new Period(referenceDate, endDate, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
}
```

The reason for your *current* output is that `normalizedStandard` is normalizing to "52 weeks, 1 day".

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeel, I tried MANY implementations. My problem was the concept of JodaTime API

Comment: @diegohsi: No, I'd say the problem is bigger than that - the idea that you can normalize "a number of days" into "a number of years, months and days" without some reference date isn't Joda-specific.